# What does Maven want?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After I completed the quest for the Thieves' Guild to deal with business at Goldenglow Estate, Brynjolf informed me that Maven Black-Briar wants to speak with me. But when I headed over to her place she had nothing to say to me except her usual stuff about how annoying I am and how important she is. I don't have a quest to talk to her either. What gives? Did she really want to talk to me or is Brynjolf just winding me up?

Comment: is the quest arrow point to maven?  It may be you have to talk to Brynjolf for some more conversation before Maven speaks to you.

Comment: Brynjolf has nothing more to say to me. He just keeps asking me how it's going. I don't have a quest involving Maven or Brynjolf or the Thieves' Guild.

Comment: hmm, sounds like a glitch then.  Have you tried talking to Mercer?

Comment: I can't find him :/

Comment: Mercer should be in the main cistern area (the area you enter if you take the secret entrance through the graveyard)

Comment: Oh yeah, I've searched around there a million times, but I haven't seen him. Now when I talk to Brynjolf he says he's got important business to do and can't talk. Mavern still won't talk to me. I'm sad :(

Comment: Located Mercer, he told me to go away.

Comment: I have the same problem. I thought it might be because I haven't performed any small quests for Delvin and Vex, so I'm trying to do them, but I really don't know. Perhaps it might stem from you have too many ongoing quests? I'm not sure...

Comment: I have this same problem. Did you find out what to do?

Comment: I made a new character and started again. I flagged this bc it's not an answer.

Comment: So if you did happen to break into honningbrew, can you not go any further with the thieves guild quests? Is there a way to skip it and go to the next one or is it just the side jobs from here on...?

Comment: If you are on the PC you can probably use the console to skip forwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug affecting other players: http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/134891-thieves-guild-dampened-spirits-quest-bug.html

Anyone know where I can report bugs? I hope a patch fixes thiss

Comment: looks like your best bet, if you don't want to wait for the patch, is to find the quest id via the console and set the stage to something appropriate.

Comment: I'm playing on xbox.

Comment: then I'm afraid you are out of luck, hopefully it'll be in next week's patch

Answer (score 0):

You can't take this quest if you have previously broken into the Honningbrew Meadery.

Answer (score -2):

When I spoke to Maven for the next part of the quest chain, I spoke with her on the second floor of the inn.  Try turning on your quest tracking only for that quest (clear the rest) and follow the arrows.

Comment: I don't have a quest, that's the problem.